VCL high DPI style prevents proper scroll bar sizing. How do I force the scrollbar to redraw?
Using Delphi 12.1 Athens:

Create a new VCL MDI application for Windows 32bit (File - New - Other, select Delphi - Windows on the left, then select MDI application, and click OK).
Select the "Windows 11 Polar Light" style in Project - Options - Appearance.
Add a panel aligned alTop
Add a button on the panel and name it NewBtn.
Add an OnClick event to each component, and add the code shown below.
Run the program.
Click the NewBtn to create one or more child forms.
Move a child form so that the vertical scrollbar is visible.
Click the panel component. It should change height, but the scrollbar will not redraw.

This has been acknowledged as a defect, but I haven't gotten any advice about a workaround. I thought I could simply resize the main window, and that works unless the window is maximized, which a lot of my users do. I tried simply calling the Resize() method, but that had no effect. I tried tracing through the VCL code, but I could not find anything that made sense to me.
object MainForm: TMainForm
  Left = 194
  Top = 111
  Caption = 'MDI Application'
  ClientHeight = 535
  ClientWidth = 610
  Color = clAppWorkSpace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clBlack
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Default'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsMDIForm
  VisualManager = FormTabsBar1
  Position = poDefault
  TextHeight = 13
  object StatusBar: TStatusBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 516
    Width = 610
    Height = 19
    Margins.Left = 2
    Margins.Top = 2
    Margins.Right = 2
    Margins.Bottom = 2
    AutoHint = True
    Panels = <>
    SimplePanel = True
  end
  object FormTabsBar1: TFormTabsBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 486
    Width = 610
    Height = 30
    Align = alBottom
    ParentColor = False
    TabOptions.ShowFormIcon = True
    TabOptions.ShowFormSystemMenu = True
    TabOptions.ShowCloseButton = True
    TabOptions.ShowHintForTruncatedCaption = True
    TabMinWidth = 100
    TabMaxWidth = 250
    Visible = False
    ShowTabsMenuButton = True
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 610
    Height = 97
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = Panel1Click
    object NewBtn: TButton
      Left = 20
      Top = 28
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'NewBtn'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = NewBtnClick
    end
  end
  object OpenDialog: TOpenDialog
    Filter = 'All files (*.*)|*.*'
    Left = 16
    Top = 272
  end
  ... Image data removed...
end

procedure TMainForm.Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Panel1.Height > 100 then
    Panel1.Height := Panel1.Height - 20
  else
    Panel1.Height := Panel1.Height + 20;
end;
    
procedure TMainForm.NewBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileNew1Execute(nil);
end;


You can use this workaround inside the Panel1Click event handler and include Vcl.Themes in the uses list:
SendMessage(Handle, WM_MDICHILDMOVE, 0, 0);


Works like a charm!
